# Need help with fixed and random effect negative binomial models in R

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, negative-binomial-distribution

This is my first time asking a question here. I am trying to develop a relationship between number of accidents on a road segment and some geometric and traffic variables. I have total 7 years of data so considering panel models. I do not have any formal education in R and pretty much teaching myself. I have been looking for an appropriate package to develop fixed and random effect negative binomial and zero iflated models. Looks like packages like pglm or similar ones only allow gaussian, poisson and binomial as "family". Any suggestion? Should I just move to SAS?

Comment: This seems mostly a software question. You may want to look at lme4 (glmer.nb function) or you could decide that a normally distributed random effect on the log event rate (Poisson GLMM with random effect) is pretty similar to a gamma distributed random effect on the event rate (Negative Binomial regression, once you integrate out the random effects) and just use a Poisson GLMM. That may not be the standard approach in your field though.

Comment: You could try the r-sig-mixed-models mailing list for advice on package choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[GLMMadaptive](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/)** package to fit zero-inflated Poisson and negative binomial models in R using the adaptive Gaussian quadrature method. This is similar to what SAS is doing (e.g., Proc NLMIXED), and it is generally considered better than doing the Laplace approximation.

For specific examples, have a look at the [Zero-Inflated and Two-Part Mixed Effects Models](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html) vignette.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking into the GLMMadaptive package. Probably need to read some more